# ancestor paths in google app engine ndb: child's parent key isn't the same as it's parent's key

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

```
def post(self):
  #Step 1: Receive POST data
  value1 = self.request.get('value1')
  value2 = self.request.get('value2')

  #Step 2: Put the ROOT entity into the database
  root = Root(name = value1)
  root.put()

  #Step 3: Link the Child entity to it's Parent entity (the Root)...
  root_key = ndb.Key(Root, value1)
  child= Child(name = value2,parent=root_key)
  #...Then put the Child entity into the database
  child.put()
```

The problem is that the key from the Root (Step 2) doesn't match that from Child (Step 3). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, try this for root_key:

```
root_key = root.put()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!!! I had spent around 2-3 hours on this problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `name` where you should be using `id`. When you create your models, you are actually **not** setting the name in the key, but rather that of a property. Because of this, `root_key`, which has `value1` as the key name, does not match the key of `root`, which will have an automatically allocated id. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Constructor) for the `Model` constructor, which has an `id` but no `name` argument:

> Arguments:
>
> Model subclasses support these keyword arguments:
>
> `key` Key instance for this model. If the key parameter is used, id and
>   parent must be None (the default).
>
> `id` Key id for this model. If id is
>   used, key must be None (the default).
>
> `parent` Key instance for the
>   parent model or None for a top-level one. If parent is used, key must
>   be None.
>
> `namespace` Namespace to use for this entity, or None (default)
>   to use the current namespace. If namespace is used, key must be None.